# Using MongoDB with PHP without ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, backend, slim, odm

I have simple MongoDB collection and I am using SLIM micro-framework to develop a RESTful mobile back-end. I don't need to implement an ODM ( Object Document Mapper ) since its very tiny collection and it wont expand in the future, but at the same time, i need to manage the MonogDB connection as we do in Singleton design pattern so I don't create instances every time I need to query MongoDB.

The question is: Does PECL MongoDB extension provided by PHP manages the connection pooling and handle this issue, or I have to write a Singleton class and totally depend on it to manage the MongoDB instances. thank you.

Comment: 1) Singletone will not keep the connection when your script will be terminated. 2) Singleton it's antipattern, try to avoid using it.

Comment: I just found that its better to use dependency injection technique instead of Singleton, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does the pooling for you. See http://php.net/mongo.connecting . Sounds like you'll also want persistent connections.

What's "single-tone"?

Comment: Sorry I missed typed the the name, its singleton http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern